# Incorporating existing html pages into Django

Tags: python, django

I have several hundred static html pages, with an index html page, that I need to bring into Django. I can't figure out the easiest way to do that, I know I'm missing something simple. Any advice?
Nothing fancy needed, just need to dump them in a directory and allow users to navigate to them.

Comment: That's a task for the webserver running in front of Django.

Comment: Those static html pages become your applications templates, you still have urls and views to write, and then to go through an update all links throughout those pages to reflect the urls (or use the template tag)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a view and a url for each html template, iI'm going to put you a simple example here but it's highly recommended that you read Django's documentation or a tutorial :

First, you create a view in a views.py file :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View


class LoadTemplateView(View):
    
    template_name = ['thenameofyourdjangoapp/yourtemplatename.html']
    #You put any code you may need here
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

Then, you must create a url that reads that view in a urls.py file :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
#Here you import from views the view you created
from .views import LoadTemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns(
       url(r'^myurl/$', LoadTemplateView.as_view(), name="load_template"),
)
```

Last, in your let's say home html template, you assign this url to a submit button in order to call it by the name you gave it on urls.py (load_template in this case) :

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div>
        <a class="option-admin" id="id_go" href ="{% url 'yourdjangoappname:load_template' %}"> Go to template </a>

  </body>
</html>
        </div>
```

As I said anyway, it's better that you read the complete Django documentation as well:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/

Answer (score 1):

If these are legacy static pages that you do not plan to touch again, then I'd leave django out of it. I'd put them all in a directory or subdomain and serve them directly from the server (probably nginx, maybe apache, whatever you're using). As a general rule, you don't want Django serving static assets, you want the proxy server serving them.

You COULD move them into Django and manage them like other Django static assets, as described in the [Managing Static Files Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/), but if they're already out there, then there's not a whole lot of advantage over just serving them as outlined above.

And finally, if you wish to fully integrate them into your Django site, then you should probably start with [the template documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/).

Comment: Thanks everybody. I knew I was making it to complicated - I like this answer! Thanks for the other approaches, too.